# Why can't I install my printer

Tags: printing

Have Samsung scx-4521f.  Even have the installation desk but can't install correct driver.Best so far is nearest driver selection in ubuntu database.  It activates the printer but don't print anything. I'm a new user, checking out Ubuntu. up to now I liked it well but not impressed with this barrier.
marv

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Installation

A few important points with the approach here:

- Some Xerox printers are Samsung OEM. This printer looks like a clone of Samsung SCX-4521F [www.samsung.com]. Treat this printer like the latter whenever possible.
- Use CUPS for the printer.
- Use the Samsung Unified Linux Driver for the scanner.

Step 1: Setup the Repository for Samsung Unified Linux Driver

No free or open-source alternatives are available to make full use of this multifunction printer yet. You will see later that we need the Samsung Unified Linux Driver mainly for supporting the scanner.

1. Add the following repository:

deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra

You can do this with Synaptic Package Manager, Software Sources, etc.
2. Install the GPG key, from http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg, for the repository. You can do this with Synaptic Package Manager or Software Sources, or paste this line to your terminal:

wget -O - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

1. Reload / update the repository information.

Step 2: Install the Printer Driver

Here, you can choose to use either one of the following drivers:

- The open-source driver provided by the Splix project. (Check this too: http://www.linuxprinting.org/show_drive ... iver=splix)
- The Samsung unified printer driver. In this case, install the samsungmfp-driver package.

Either of the drivers seems to work fine. I personally do not have any particular recommendation yet until further testing. (For the moment I use the Splix driver.)

1. From the start menu, invoke System -> Administration -> Printing.
2. Use the driver for 'Samsung SCX-4500 Series'. Choose either the Splix or the Samsung driver according to your preference.
3. Check the 'Printer Options' in the 'Printer Properties'. Change the options where appropriate (especially the 'Paper Size').
4. Try to print a test page. It should work!

Step 3: Install the Scanner Driver

1. Install the samsungmfp-scanner package.
2. {SKIP THIS for Ubuntu since 10.04. But tell me if you found that this step is necessary for the scanner to work.} Add users you allow to access the scanner into the lp group. You can use System -> Users and Groups from the start menu to do this, or use the adduser command.
3. Reboot the computer. (Restarting some service(s) should do the trick too. But I haven't figured out which one. Tell me if you've found it.)
4. Now Graphics -> Simple Scan or xsane should be able to detect and use the scanner! You can use sane-find-scanner or scanimage -L to detect the scanner too.